# how to call the default destructor of a class if there is no destructor defined by the programmer in php

Tags: php, class

if there is no destructor defined in a class how to call the destructor if needed?

__destruct() is not the default destructor of a class. then how to call the default destructor from inside a class? hence if i don't define any __destruct() method in the parent class i can't call it from a child class. how to do it?

```
class c1
{
    public $a=10;
    public function f1()
    {
        self::__destruct();//Fatal error: Call to undefined method c1::__destruct()
    }
}

$obj1_c1 = new c1();
$obj1_c1->f1();
```

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to call the default destructor of a class if no destructor is defined.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the method exists using `method_exists()`.

Another problem is that you are trying to call the method statically using `self` but you need to call `$this::__destruct()` instead. Here comes an example:

```
class Test {

    public function foo() {
        if(method_exists($this, '__destruct')) {
            $this->__destruct();
        }
        // if the method does not exist then there is simply no
        // desctructor and therefore nothing to call 
    }
}

$t = new Test();
$t->foo();
```

Comment: actually here i am trying to use destructor of the same class

Comment: This is wrong, run it will be get `Fatal error: Cannot access parent:: when current class scope has no parent`

Comment: @RajeshPaul I'm not sure that I got your question completely. Please ask if something is wrong with my answer

Comment: actually here i am trying to use destructor of the same class

I just want to know if there is a way to call the default destructor of a class or not if no __destruct() method is defined explicitly.

here is not any issue with any parent class I just want to do it inside a single class.

Comment: On a different note - why on earth would you CALL a destructor in the first place? It's not your job to invoke destructor. It's just a convenience for a developer when PHP is performing shutdown. If it's there, it gets called. If not, nothing happens. If you found yourself in "need" to call a destructor - your app design is bad and that's the first sign of it.

Comment: @N.B. I was about to say the same but I think there could be situations where it could make sense.. Something like an object re-initialization.. However it is more theoretical. Usually `__destruct()` is a hook meant to be called by the zend engine, of course

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the destruct method. You unset your instance if you want to delete it.

```
unset(obj1_c1);
```

This will call the default `__destruct`.

Comment: I just want to know if there is a way to call the default destructor of a class if no destructor is defined.

Comment: Then do as hek2mgl said. Just know this is probably a bad practice depending of what you want to do.

Comment: U mean to say that calling the default destructor is useless?

Comment: Yes. You should use unset if you want to delete your object instance, not call the __destruct() function. Even if you have a custom one, you should let php use it by itself.

Comment: Calling __destruct() (if it exists) doesn't actually destroy the instance, it only executes the code in the __destruct() method... if you unset an instance, and their is a __destruct() method, then that code is automatically executed before the instance is destroyed, but __destruct() isn't responsible for the actual destruction

Comment: @MarkBaker: thanx for the logical answer.

Comment: @MarkBaker You're right Mark. However, I assume the OP wants to destroy his instance, hence my answer. In any case, I wouldn't recommend calling a custom __destruct() if you want to run the code inside it without destroying the instance. Just put it somewhere else and use __destruct() for what it's intended.

Comment: @Kethryweryn - I wasn't addressing you with that comment, more a case of trying to clarify for the OP